# uniqueness of solutions for laplace equation

Tags: laplacian

I know that the solutions to the Laplace equation $\triangle u=0$ are unique but in some cases one can find that there is more than 1 solution. For example $u=0$ and ln$|\textbf{x}|$ are both solutions to $\triangle u=0, u=0$ on $|\textbf{x}|=1$. How does this not contradict uniqueness?

Comment: Notice that $\ln\lvert x\rvert$ is not defined on the disk, but rather on the disk minus its center. The domain of definition comes heavily into play in existence and uniqueness of solutions to PDEs.

Comment: Also boundary conditions are important for what the unique solution is. In your example you have not given any boundary conditions at $|\mathbf{x}|=0.$ Your two solutions have very different values there.